# Referencing a Control with a String

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an USB controller, Xk-60 from P.I. Engineering, is configure and working properly.
The following code read if a key is pressed on the controller and select a case based on the returned CID value. All good until here.
Now a like to refer to several Checkbox dynamically also using the CID value.
I don't seem to find the right way ...

This is not valid:

```
If e.PressState = True And **ctl.Checked** = False Then
```

---

```
Private Sub Xk60_80_1_ButtonChange(ByVal e As XK_60_80.XKeyEventArgs) Handles Xk60_80_1.ButtonChange
    Select Case e.CID
        Case 1001
            Dim nbr As String = e.CID.ToString().Remove(0, 3)
            Dim ctl() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("CheckBox" & nbr, True)
            If e.PressState = True And ctl.Checked = False Then              
                CheckBox1.Checked = True
            ElseIf e.PressState = True And CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
                CheckBox1.Checked = False
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Me.Controls.Find` returns an array of controls.

Also `Control` has no `Checked`-property so it's better to search only the controls of type `CheckBox` and use the first found with the appropriate name:

```
Dim ctl As CheckBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).
                      First(Function(c) c.Name = "CheckBox" & nbr)

If e.PressState = True AndAlso ctl IsNot Nothing AndAlso ctl.Checked = False Then
    CheckBox1.Checked = True
ElseIf e.PressState = True And CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    CheckBox1.Checked = False
End If
```

Also it's better to use short-circuiting like already mentioned in Tim Schmelter's answer.

Comment: This approach has one drawback. Unlike `Controls.Find` `Controls.OfType` is not searching for the control recursively. So if it's contained in a child control like a `Panel` you won't find it.

Comment: Or cycle i from 0 to ctl.count-1 and set ctl(i).enabled = False

Comment: Great this works for me. Not searching recursively is a drawback indeed.
Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2):

`Controls.Find` returns a `Control()`, so possibly multiple controls. If you want the first:

```
Dim checkBoxControl = TryCast(ctl.ElementAtOrDefault(0), CheckBox)

CheckBox1.Checked = e.PressState AndAlso 
                    checkBoxControl IsNot Nothing AndAlso 
                    Not checkBoxControl.Checked
```

Note that i have used `AnsAlso` instead of `And` which is a short-circuiting operator which stops if the previous condition is not met. Otherwise you would get a `NullReferenceException` at `checkBoxControl.Checked` if `checkBoxControl` was already `Nothing`. So use `AndAlso`(and `OrElse`).